# Determine new record in PreWriteRecord event handler and check value of joined field

Tags: oracle, event-handling, crm, siebel, escript

There is custom field "Lock Flag" in Account BC, namely in S_ORG_EXT_X table. This field is made available in Opportunity BC using join to above table. The join specification is as follows: Opportunity.Account Id = Account.Id. Account Id is always populated when creating new opportunity. The requirement is that for newly created records in Opportunity BC if "Lock Flag" is equal to 'Y', then we should not allow to create the record and we should show custom error message.

My initial proposal was to use a Runtime Event that is calling Data Validation Manager business service where validation rule is evaluated and error message shown. Assuming that we have to decide whether to write record or not, the logic should be placed in PreWriteRecord event handler as long as WriteRecord have row already commited to database.

The main problem was how to determine if it is new record or updated one. We have WriteRecordNew and WriteRecordUpdated runtime events but they are fired after record is actually written so it doesn't prevent user from saving record. My next approach was to use eScript: write custom code in BusComp_PreWriteRecord server script and call BC's method IsNewRecordPending to determine if it is new record, then check the flag and show error message if needed.

But unfortunately I am faced with another problem. That joined field "Lock Flag" is not populated for newly created opportunity records. Remember we are talking about BC Opportunity and field is placed in S_ORG_EXT_X table. When we create new opportunity we pick account that it belongs to. So it reproduceable: OpportunityBC.GetFieldValue("Lock Flag") returns null for newly created record and returns correct value for the records that was saved previously. For newly created opportunities we have to re-query BC to see "Lock Flag" populated. I have found several documents including [Oracle's recomendation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B40099_02/books/ConfigApps/ConfigApps_Procedures_business_layer17.html) to use PreDefaultValue property if we want to display joined field value immediately after record creation. The most suitable expression that I've found was Parent: BCName.FieldName but it is not the case, because active BO is Opportunity and Opportunity BC is the primary one.

Thanks for your patience if you read up to here and finally come my questions:

1. Is there any way to handle PreWrite event and determine if it is new record or not, without using eScript and BC.IsNewRecordPending method?
2. How to get value of joined field for newly created record especially in PreWriteRecord event handler?

It is Siebel 8.1

**UPDATE:** I have found an answer for the first part of my question. Now it seems so simple to me that I am wondering how I haven't done it initially. Here is the solution.

1. Create Runtime Event triggered on PreWriteRecord. Specify call to Data Validation Manager business service.
2. In DVM create a ruleset and a rule where condition is

> NOT(BCHasRows("Opportunity", "Opportunity", "[Id]='"+[Id]+"'", "AllView"))

That's it. We are searching for record wth the same Row Id. If it is new record there should't be anything in database yet (remember that we are in PreWriteRecord handler) and function returns FALSE. If we are updating some row then we get TRUE. Reversing result with NOT we make DVM raise an error for new records.

As for second part of my question credits goes to @RanjithR who proposed to use PickMap to populate joined field (see below). I have checked that method and it works fine at least when you have appropriate PickMap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We Siebel developers have used scripting to correctly determine if record is new. One non scripting way you could try is to use RuntimeEvents to set a profileattribute during the BusComp NewRecord event, then check that in the PreWrite event to see if the record is new. However, there is always a chance that user might undo a record, those scenarios are tricky.

Another option, try invokine the BC Method:IsNewRecordPending from RunTime event. I havent tried this.

For the second part of the query, I think you could easily solve your problem using a PickMap.

On Opportunity BC, when your pick Account, just add one more pickmap to pick the Locked flag from Account and set it to the corresponding field on Opportunity BC. When the user picks the Account, he will also pick the lock flag, and your script will work in PreWriteRecord.

May I suggest another solution, again, I haven't tried it.

When new records are created, the field ModificationNumber will be set to 0. Every time you modify it, the ModificationNumber will increment by 1.

Set a DataValidationManager ruleset, trigger it from PreSetFieldValue event of Account field on Opportunity BC. Check for the LockFlag = Y AND (ModificationNumber IS NULL OR ModificationNumber = 0)) and throw error. DVM should throw error when new records are created.

Again, best practices say don't use the ModNumbers. You could set a ProfileAttribute to signal NewRecord, then use that attribute in the DVM. But please remember to clear the value of  ProfileAttribute in WriteRecord and UndoRecord.

Let us know how it went !

Comment: Concerning calculated field actually I have already done it that way which you proposed. After trying various PreDefaultValue expressions I started thinking is there another method to do it. Shortly PickMap came in my mind and after testing I can say that it works.

I also have found the way to check for new record without scripting and will update my question soon. Anyway thanks for your all suggestions!

Comment: Hi Yaroslav, it is a neat trick using BCHasRows, never thought of it. But if you are querying in all view in the BC, it might start showing performance issues in the long run. But, neat trick neverthless :-D

Comment: Well ROW_ID column has unique index. Certainly the query consumes some resources but I believe not too much. :)